# Copying arraylist values within itself

Tags: c#

Consider i have ArrayLists like these,

1){int[],int,int[]}
2){int[],int[],int}
And i have a count, 'n'. If n is 3 then my arrayList should be,

1){int[],int[],int[],int,int[],int[],int[]}

2){int[],int[],int[],int[],int[],int[],int}

i.e The new ArrayList should contain 'n' times the Array int[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, do you really have to use an `ArrayList`? The fact that you're holding different types of data in one collection suggests there's probably a better way of solving your problem. Anyway, you could do something like this:

```
public static ArrayList DuplicateIntArrays(ArrayList input, int copies)
{
    ArrayList ret = new ArrayList();
    foreach (object element in input)
    {
        if (element is int[])
        {
            for (int i=0; i < copies; i++)
            {
                ret.Add(element);
            }
        }            
        else
        {
            ret.Add(element);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```